# Alternatives to log shipping / Replicate a local SQL Server database on a remote DB accesible only by IP

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I'm trying to replicate a local SQL Server 2008R2 DB to a remote DB instance accessible only by IP (specifically, a RackSpace cloud site DB). I believe log shipping is ideal, since the remote only needs to be kept up to date occasionally, and data transfer is one-way. However, I cannot get this configured as attempting to use the RackSpace as the secondary in the config generates an error that I must be a member of the sysadmin fixed role on that instance. So I have two questions:

- Is the sysadmin role fixable?
- If not, what are my options for replicating data from a local SQL Server instance to a remote instance?

Comment: Are you using some wizard for log shipping? Why? You can do this easily with simple backup and restore commands you write yourself, and skip any silly account validation that the wizard is doing. (Of course, you need to run the restore at RackSpace as an account with the rights to restore a database and its logs, and you need to copy the files to somewhere that the remote database can see - surely they provide FTP or some similar mechanism to move files to their servers.)

Comment: As Aaron says, it should be nearly trivial to create the script to log ship yourself. However, you need a way to get the log files from the source to the target. When you say that the instance is accessible "only by IP", do you mean only on a specific port or just that it does not have a DNS entry?

Comment: It's only accessible on a specific port. I suspect I can still perform backup/restore via the ip:port combo, which I'll try this afternoon. Manually doing the log shipping may be the way to go.